# in my wall of php code this specific piece of code isnt working this is the invalid password error and please contact an admin

Tags: php

This is where i get the issue

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con, $username);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con, $password);

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT password, admin, id FROM members WHERE username=?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);

    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* bind result variables */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $hash, $admin, $id);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

    if($stmt->num_rows == 1) {  //To check if the row exists

        if($stmt->fetch()) {

            if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {

                $sql4 = "UPDATE members SET last_login='".$today."' WHERE id='".$id."'";

                if ($con->query($sql4) === TRUE) {
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['admin'] = $admin;
                    header("location:staff_portal/");
                } else {
                    echo "Contact Admin as Record can't be updated.";
                }
            {
                echo "Invalid password.";
            }
        }
    } else {

        echo "Username or Password is wrong.";
    }

    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

The "Username or Password is wrong." is working just nothing else

Comment: apparently, you have a problem with your condition. then *why don't you post the condition*?

Comment: Please provide more detail with entire code.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: you forgot to put `else` before the bracket above 'invalid password'. Indent your code properly and fix bracket inconsistency before you test again.

Comment: i should have stated this clearly sorry again but if i type in the password correctly it works. if i purposely entered in the username wrong it would bring up a message stating you have entered the username wrong. i would want this to happen to the password aswell

Comment: Bad idea. Imagine someone attempting to breakin. If you tell them the password is wrong. they know they have found a valid userid and all that is left is to hack at the password

Comment: Thanks My Friend ive just sorted the issue out now thanks to your help ive also took into mind on what you just said i just stated that the username or password is incorrect

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an ELSE in your code. Nicely indented code shows this in a second

See the code I have annotated where.

You are also using `mysqli_real_escape_string` once where it is not needed and once where it can actually cause you problems

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
// not needed
//$username = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con, $username);
// dangerous, as it may change the passwrd entered by the user
// and as its not used in a concatenated query unnecessary anyway
//$password = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con, $password);

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT password, admin, id FROM members WHERE username=?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);
    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    /* bind result variables */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $hash, $admin, $id);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
    if($stmt->num_rows == 1) {  //To check if the row exists
        if($stmt->fetch()) {
            if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {

                //I dont see anywhere where $today is initialized
                // NOW() would have been all you needed assuming last_login
                // Is a DATETIME/DATE/TIMESTAMP Column
                $sql4 = "UPDATE members SET last_login='".$today."' WHERE id='".$id."'";

                if ($con->query($sql4) === TRUE) {
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['admin'] = $admin;
                    header("location:staff_portal/");
                } else {
                    echo "Contact Admin as Record can't be updated.";
                }
            } else {
//----------^^^^^^ this was missing

                echo "Invalid password.";
            }
        }
    } else {

        echo "Username or Password is wrong.";
    }

    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```